# Gson ignores list of Strings

Tags: serialization, kotlin, gson

I have model which contains list of strings

`data class BSLQuery(var contentTypeKeys: List<String>? = null, ...)`

When I'm trying to convert model to JSON

`gson.toJson(query)`

gson always ignores contentTypeKeys.

Typical data for unmapped field

`BSLQuery(contentTypeKeys = listOf("com.assignment.attachment")`

How I can convert it correctly?

**EDIT**

Actual result JSON: `{...}`

Required result JSON: `{"contentTypeKeys":["com.assignment.attachment"], ...}`

Comment: Show us the json file please

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS added

Comment: I need to see what you receive from server

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I'm trying to configure request in this case I don't interacting with server at all

Comment: Are you sure your `query` object contains list value for `contentTypeKeys` not `null` ?

Comment: @IDon'tExist yes, I put break point to model before it maps to json. And model contains valid contentTypeKeys